# how to execute two function same time in perl by threads?

Tags: perl

I new to thread concept in perl, How can I execute two function same time in perl? How can I start this concept?

### my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

&one;
&two;

sub one{
    print $_, " " for (1..10);
}
sub two{
    print $_, "\n" for (1..10);
}

my output:
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
...
...
```

How can I run this two function same time by threads or and any other way... ?

my output:

```
welcome (01:12 AM)
welcome (01:12 AM)
```

Thanks advance...

Answer (score 6):

```
use threads;
my $t = async { one() };
two();
$t->join();
```

You won't get that nice output without some synchronisation, though.