# How to run subroutine in parallel?

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  method1();
}

sub method1()
    {
           // here do something
    }
```

Here I called method1 subroutine in for loop. Here, I want this method1 subroutine to be called (in parallel) without waiting for the result of previous call. How to do that ? Is there any other method other than thread ?

Comment: you can use fork or thread to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16475586/223226

Comment: If I write the subroutine as separate script, then which could satisfy the above concept by calling another script and how to do that  (Exec and system) ?

Comment: Exec will not do what you want without at least the use of `fork()` but then you've already got the forked process & don't need to Exec.  `system()`, with very creative use of bash background processes may provide a brutish hack that may meet your needs after much work.  Seriously, `use threads` or `fork()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to execute two function same time in perl by threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475531/how-to-execute-two-function-same-time-in-perl-by-threads)

Comment: "Is there any other method other than thread ?" leaves us guessing as to what problem you have with threads. How can we address the issue if you don't say what it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Threads:

```
use threads;

for (0..4) {
    async { f() };
}

$_->join() for threads->list;
```

---

Processes:

```
use forks;

for (0..4) {
    async { f() };
}

$_->join() for forks->list;
```

---

Coro threads:

```
use Coro;

my @threads;
for (0..4) {
    push @threads, async { f() };
}

$_->join() for @threads;
```

Coro provides a cooperative multitasking system, so other threads only get a chance to execute when the current one becomes blocked waiting for a event.